# How to merge rows in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, unique

I have the following dataset:

[image]

I want the result to be :
[image]

How do I do this?

I tried groupby JVNo but it didnt give the desired result

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow!  please following the guidelines in posting questions here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  

No Images. dataframe as a code (preferably) or text, help to reproduce the scenario

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`df1 = pd.read_csv('a.csv', index_col='JVNo')`

`print(df1)` # will show your first table (your dataset)

`df1_cleaned = df1.select_dtypes(object).groupby(level=0).first()`

`print(df1_cleaned)` # will show your second table (what you want)